# SVN SSL connection error E120171

Tags: svn, ssl, tortoisesvn

I am using CloudForge as SVN repository for some files. Communication is SSL encrypted via HTTPS
This setup has been working for some time until last month.
The faulty client is Windows 7/64b

Symptoms:

- TortoiseSVN and command line "svn" throw SSL connection error (E121170: Error running context: An error occured during SSL communication)
- Initially, I was experiencing the issue only with WIFI, then also with cabled connection

Things I tried without success:

- Got a hold of (very nice) CouldForce support which did not see a problem on their side.
- Upgraded TortoiseSVN to latest (1.8.10)
- Reinstall TortoiseSVN from scratch, reboot

Things I tried with success:

- I can use TortoiseSVN from another computer pointing to the same repo.
- I can browse the repo using Chrome/https on the faulty computer.
- I have not seen any entries in the .ssl directory specific to CloudForge

**Can you share ideas on how to resolve this?**

Comment: I have the same problem it should have to do something with SSL3 handshaking.